# How to get count and sum with multiple parameter in case when

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, sum, case

I have the following table in MySQL (Version - 5.7.18-log).

```
ID      Old_Date       Curr_Date             Status       Price       items
ID-1    2021-07-14     2021-09-30 13:15:15   Done         1500        3
ID-1    2021-06-26     2021-09-30 13:15:15   Hold         3500        6
ID-1    2021-05-26     2021-09-30 13:15:15   In Progress  4500        1
ID-1    2021-03-04     2021-09-30 13:15:15   Done         5000        3
ID-1    2021-01-11     2021-09-30 13:15:15   Done         2800        2
```

From the above table, I need to fetch the count & sum of instances where status is `Done` and `Hold` in the last 1, 6, and 9-month intervals.

The interval needs to be calculated between `Old_Date` and `Curr_Date`.

Required Output-

```
ID     1_Month_Count  6_Month_Count  9_Month_Count   1_Month_Sum  6_Month_Sum  9_Month_Sum
ID-1   0              2              4               0            5000         12800
```

I have tried following query but It is not working.

```
SELECT ID,
SUM(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(month, Old_Date, Curr_Date) <= 12  
WHEN (Status IN ('Done', 'Hold') THEN SUM(ID) ELSE 0 END) AS 12_Month_Done`,
FROM Table
Group BY ID;
```

Comment: What is your month calculation logic. example 1 ('2021-01-01'  & '2021-06-28') example 2 ('2021-01-17' & '2021-07-05'). Please check the two example

Comment: @RahulBiswas - It is bases on `Curr_Date` minus `Old_Date` along with given condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want in the results only the `ID`s that match your conditions then use conditional aggregation after filtering the table:

```
SELECT ID,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Old_Date >= Curr_Date - INTERVAL 1 month THEN 1 END) AS `1_Month_Count`,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Old_Date >= Curr_Date - INTERVAL 6 month THEN 1 END) AS `6_Month_Count`,
       COUNT(*) AS `9_Month_Count`, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Old_Date >= Curr_Date - INTERVAL 1 month THEN Price ELSE 0 END) AS `1_Month_Sum`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Old_Date >= Curr_Date - INTERVAL 6 month THEN Price ELSE 0 END) AS `6_Month_Sum`,
       SUM(Price) AS `9_Month_Sum`            
FROM tablename
WHERE Status IN ('Done', 'Hold') AND Old_Date >= Curr_Date - INTERVAL 9 month
GROUP BY ID;
```

If you want all the `ID`s even if they don't match the conditions:

```
SELECT ID,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Old_Date >= Curr_Date - INTERVAL 1 month 
            AND Status IN ('Done', 'Hold') THEN 1 END) AS `1_Month_Count`,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Old_Date >= Curr_Date - INTERVAL 6 month 
            AND Status IN ('Done', 'Hold') THEN 1 END) AS `6_Month_Count`,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Old_Date >= Curr_Date - INTERVAL 9 month 
            AND Status IN ('Done', 'Hold') THEN 1 END) AS `9_Month_Count`, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Old_Date >= Curr_Date - INTERVAL 1 month 
            AND Status IN ('Done', 'Hold') THEN Price ELSE 0 END) AS `1_Month_Sum`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Old_Date >= Curr_Date - INTERVAL 6 month 
            AND Status IN ('Done', 'Hold') THEN Price ELSE 0 END) AS `6_Month_Sum`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Old_Date >= Curr_Date - INTERVAL 9 month 
            AND Status IN ('Done', 'Hold') THEN Price ELSE 0 END) AS `9_Month_Sum`            
FROM tablename
GROUP BY ID;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e6f0a228621bb94413ec8660ab1a70b3).

Answer (score 0):

I think a stored procedure would be a way to achieve this.
In this procedure you will have to do 3 queries for 1, 6 and 9 months.
like

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) as cnt_id, SUM(price) as sum_price INTO 1_month_count, 1_month_sum WHERE status = 'Hold' OR status = 'Done' AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, old_date, curr_date) >= 1 AND  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, old_date, curr_date) < 6;
```

then you return your variables 1_month_count etc. by

```
SELECT @1_month_count, @1_month_sum; /*and all others*/
```

More information about store procedures with OUT parameters can be found here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html